# Java writing file - Access is denied

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm trying to write a file using netbeans to a path inside the project directory so that other people on other PC's don't get error messages when running the same project (unable to find C://user...)

```
try {
    File file = new File("producten.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, false);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    for (int i = 0; i < db.getNumberOfItems(); i++) {
        bw.write("example1" + "\t");
        bw.write("example1" + "\t");
        bw.write("\r\n");
    }
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I'm getting the console error message:

```
 Access is denied
```

When I use a absolute path directed to my desktop directory it works.

Comment: unable to find C://user. - Try `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the use home directory.

Comment: Check your current directory / try with admin privileges

Comment: Using Properties > Security, I have changed all permissions to Full control (includes modify) but still the error shows.

Comment: Which MS Windows are you using, and where is your NetBeans project stored? Mine is the default `C:\Users\me\Documents\NetBeansProjects` and it works fine. What are the privileges of your user? Does it have admin privilege? Please update these in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Locate netbeans exe file. Go to properties then compatibility
Scroll down to find and check run this program as administrator.
Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by selecting sub folder in **C** drive

**Example**

```
try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\TestFolder\\DEBUG.txt");
        fileWriter.append("Hello World! \n");
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this will help who is still stuck with it.

Answer (score -3):

You do not have write permission to that directory.